# What is the most used ERC20 implementation?

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

I understand ERC20 is a specification. I found some implementations like the following:

- https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard
- https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens

I want to create my own token. What is the most used ERC20 implementation? I'd like to use that.

---

**Update**

Thanks to Abhishek's suggestion, I found an [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity) tutorial which integrates with truffle. Quite easy to understand!

[Robust Smart Contracts with OpenZeppelin](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/robust-smart-contracts-with-openzeppelin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ERC20 is standard for ethereum token. You can use it.

More specifically, you can use ["Open Zeppelin"](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity) for extra security and inbuild libraries.

Comment: thank you. seems open zeppelin has token contract and examples. very useful.